# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'show_credit'

Tags: python, json, class, dictionary, object

I try to create an object saving account and store it in a dictionary and this works fine but when i try to use the object of the dictionary with an method i get an error, so im not sure what im doing wrong?

I hope you guys understand what im trying to say and if somebody has an easier way to get the what i look for please let me know.

thanks

```
def print_accounts(accounts):
    print(accounts)
    
    pass

def add_savingaccount(account_name, iban, name, address, accounts): 
    print(accounts, name)
    accounts[name]=account_name
    account_name = SavingAccount(iban , name, address)

    
    pass

def get_savingaccount(accounts, name):
    current_account = (accounts.get(name, 'Name nicht verfügbar'))
    print(current_account)
    user_answer = int(input("What do you want to do 1. get credit, 2. withdraw, 3. deposit, 4. close account, 5. open account, 6. change rate, 7. sleep: "))
    
    if user_answer == 1:
        current_account.encode().decode().show_credit()
    
    elif user_answer == 2:
        current_account.withdrawn(int(input("How much do you want to withdraw: ")))
        
    elif user_answer == 3:
        current_account.deposit(int(input("How much do you want to deposit: ")))
        
    elif user_answer == 4:
        current_account.close_account()
        
    elif user_answer == 5:
        current_account.open_account()
        
    elif user_answer == 6:
        current_account.change_interest_rate(int(input("How much do you want to deposit: ")))
        
    elif user_answer == 7:
        current_account.sleep(int(input("Sleep time: ")))
        
    
    pass


def load_accounts(accounts, filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        accounts = json.load(file)
        #for key in phone_book:
        #   accounts[key]=phone_book[key]
        accounts.update(accounts)
    
    pass

def save_accounts(accounts, filename):

    with open(filename, "w+") as new_file:
        json.dump(accounts, new_file, separators=(',',':'))
    
    
    pass

def print_menu():
    print ('1. Print Phone Numbers')
    print ('2. Add a SavingAccount')
    print ('4. Get SavingAccount')
    print ('5. Load accounts')
    print ('6. Save accounts')
    print ('7. Quit')
    print()

accounts = {}
menu_choice = 0
print_menu()


while True:
    menu_choice = int(input("Type in a number (1-7): "))
    if menu_choice == 1:
        print_accounts(accounts)
        print_menu()

        
    elif menu_choice == 2:
        print("Add Name and Number (Valid IBAN gets transferred)")
        account_name = input("Accountname: ")
        name = input("Name: ")
        iban = "CH 54 3242 3345 5342 4235"
        address = input("Address: ")
        add_savingaccount(account_name, iban, name, address, accounts)
        print_menu()

        
        
    elif menu_choice == 4:
        print("get_savingaccount")
        name = input("Name: ")
        get_savingaccount(accounts, name)
        print_menu()

        
    elif menu_choice == 5:
        filename = input("Filename to load: ")
        load_accounts(accounts, filename)
        print_menu()

        
    elif menu_choice == 6:
        filename = input("Filename to save: ")
        save_accounts(accounts, filename)
        print_menu()

        
    elif menu_choice == 7:
        break
    
    else:
        print_menu()
```

Comment: Your `add_savingaccount` function assigns the `SavingAccount` object to the argument `account_name` then exits without saving or returning it. The `accounts` dict then contains only a mapping of customer names to account names, which doesn't seem like what you meant to do.

Comment: Yes thats right but i dont know how make it better

Comment: Try `accounts[name] = SavingAccount(iban, account_name, address)`.